# Derivation of Bellman equation for state value function V(s)

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, expected-value

I'm studying reinforcement learning from Richard S. Sutton book, where the derivation of Bellman equation is given as following:

$$v_\pi(s) = E_\pi(R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1} | S_t = s)$$
$$=\sum_a \pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}\sum_rp(s', r|s, a)[r + \gamma E_\pi([G_{t+1}|S_{t+1} = s])]$$

I don't understand how this equation arrived from first one. [here](https://joshgreaves.com/reinforcement-learning/understanding-rl-the-bellman-equations/) is one another resource explaining the same. But at both the places the same equation is derived. So What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we follow policy $\pi$, given that we are at state $s$.

Then with probability $\pi(a|s)$, we take action $a$.

Given that we are at state $s$ and $a$, with probability $p(s',r|s,a)$, we receive reward $r$ and arrive at state $s'$.

That is by the law of total expectation,

\begin{align}
&E_\pi (R_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1}|S_t=s) \\&= \sum_{r,s', a} E_\pi (R_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1}|R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s', A=a,S_t=s)Pr(R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s', A=a|S_t=s) \\
&=\sum_{r,s', a} Pr(R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s', A=a|S_t=s)E_\pi (R_{t+1}+\gamma G_{t+1}|R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s', A=a,S_t=s) \\
&=\sum_{r,s', a} Pr(A=a|S_t=s) Pr(R_{t+1}=r, S_{t+1}=s'|A=a, S_t=s)E_\pi (r+\gamma G_{t+1}| S_{t+1}=s', A=a,S_t=s) \\
&=\sum_{r,s', a} \pi(a|s)p(s',r|s,a)E_\pi (r+\gamma G_{t+1}| S_{t+1}=s'),  \\
&=\sum_{r,s', a} \pi(a|s)p(s',r|s,a)[r+\gamma E_\pi (G_{t+1}| S_{t+1}=s')]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this confused me even more.

Comment: which part is not clear?

Comment: the first step itself. I can't relate it with the definition of expectation.

Comment: Perhaps, the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) might help. The whole idea is to consider all possible outcome and weight the corresponding conditional expectation by the  corresponding probability.

Comment: Understood the first two steps! how the third one derived from second step?

Comment: I replace $R_{t+1}$ with $r$ since it is now given. Also $Pr(BC|D)=Pr(B|D)Pr(C|BD)$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your interest and time! Accepted and +1

Comment: These are just details, most would just jump from first to last line by viewing the corresponding probability and outcome directly.